# Float values which ends with '0' cant be denoted by two decimal points

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting, formatter

I do a number formatting to indicate currency values as follows :

```
 private static DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

 List<String> paidAmounts = new ArrayList<>();

  for (Invoice invoice : invoices) {
    paidAmounts.add(String.valueOf
    ("$"+Formatter.currencyDecimalFormat(invoice.getAmount())));
   }

   public static Float currencyDecimalFormat(int value) {
    return Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format((float) value / 100));
}
```

Invoice class :

```
    private int amount;

    public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }
```

But the values which ends with '0' are not formatted to the desirable format.

```
$18.5
$16.8
$105.59
```

How to make this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Float.valueOf` is reformatting the `float` to remove the trailing `0` because a *float* cannot hold a trailing 0.  The `String` that `.format` returns *can*.  If you try printing out:

> decimalFormat.format((float) value / 100)

The float numbers will print correctly.  Remove this call to `.valueOf` and return a `String` from `currencyDecimalFormat`instead:

```
public static String currencyDecimalFormat(int value) {
    return decimalFormat.format((float) value / 100);
}
```